# How can I use Cognito to authenticate requests to my API without using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

Seems like all the information on using Cognito to protect APIs requires using AWS API Gateway, but this gateway costs extra and there are many other API Gateway products available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could present the id or access token returned by Cognito to whatever API system you are using and validate the tokens yourself.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html